# Overlaping objects in VBA - text frame not visible

Tags: excel, vba, object, text

I have such problem: I am adding several objects (hexagons with 90deg rotation) in VBA code. **Each object** has 3 lines of text but between 2nd and 3rd text is a new line separation. I have no idea why the objects are overlapping (the range borders of each object are square but transparent, so I assume the problem may lay in here) in the way that visible are only the 2 first line of text. It looks like this:[3 hexagons overlapping text frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iThhN.jpg)

The right-bottom hexagon is selected and only then I can see the whole text frame.
I would like to see all 3 lines of text bud I do not know how to do it (or bring it to the foreground somehow).
Here is the code

```
With ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(10, e, d, 135, 117)
        .Rotation = 90                                          
        .TextFrame.Characters.Font.Size = 18                    
        .TextFrame.Characters.Font.Color = 1
        .TextFrame.HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignCenter                 
        .TextFrame.Orientation = 2
        .TextFrame.Characters.Text =“Text1” & vbNewLine & "Text2" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine  & “Text3”
        .TextFrame.Characters(1, 4).Font.Bold = True
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)                      
        .Line.Weight = 1                                      
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .Line.Style = msoLineSingle
    End With
```

Answer (score 0):

in your code

```
  .TextFrame.Characters.Text =“Text1” & vbNewLine & "Text2" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine  & “Text3”
```

The words Text1 and text3 are not surrounded by speech marks, but some sort of 'smart quotes'. when I replace them with true speech marks your code works.